# SQL "IN" combined with "=" in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with someone else's code.  What might the WHERE clause do in the following (MySQL) statement?

```
    SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id IN (1,2,3)
```

It's not providing the desired result in my case, but I'm trying to figure what the original author intended.
Can anyone provide an example of the use of a WHERE clause like this?

Comment: What the DB you are using, If I am not wrong this syntax was supported in SQL Server 2000, but not later

Comment: I'd say it's a bug if that syntax is actually allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This condition starts from the right, evaluates `t2.id IN (1,2,3)`, gets the result (0 or 1), and uses it for join with `t1.id`. All rows of `t2` with `id` from the `IN` list are joined to the row in `t1` that has `id` of one; all other rows of `t2` are joined with the row in `t1` that has `id` of zero. Here is a small demo on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/): [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8815c/3).

It is hard to imagine that that was the intent of the author, however: I think a more likely check was for both items to be in the list, and also being equal to each other. The equality to each other is important, because it looks like the author wanted to join the two tables.

A more modern way of doing joins is with ANSI SQL syntax. Here is the equivalent of your query in ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: It's interesting that on a correspondent page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html there is not even a single word about associativity (+1 from me)

Comment: I think it's the other way around... the IN is evaluated first and then it's result is used to join. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f2f5/1

Comment: @AndreKR I think you're right - it looks like `IN` has higher priority than `=`. I don't know why I thought it was going left-to-right. I rewrote the answer to take this into account. Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that the result can be `0`, `1` or `NULL`.  `0` when the condition (`t2.id IN (1,2,3)`) evaluates to `FALSE`, `1` when it's `TRUE` and `NULL` when it's `UNKNOWN`.